# How to do an integration of a lightbox in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, lightbox

Is there a best practice how to integrate a lightbox in TYPO3?
Shall I use an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 has prepared the integration for you. In the TYPO3 Constant Editor (Module Template) you have the possibility to activate lightbox:

[image: lightbox configuration TYPO3 Backend]

Now you are able to integrate any lightbox JS you like.
Download JS and CSS files and add it in the PAGE TypoScript (into the footer for performance issues):

```
page.includeJSFooterlibs.lightbox = location/to/lightbox/js/file.js
page.includeCSS.lightbox = location/to/lightbox/css/file.css
```

If you need to configure your lightbox, add your own JS file:

```
page.includeJSFooter.script = location/to/own/config/js/file.js
```

Finally, you only need to set the option `Enlarge on click` whenever you add media to a content element:

[image: How to activate lightbox in TYPO3 Backend]